# I write This Code in Function.php...But Its not Show Delivery day

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

1.(Cakes,Chocos Flavour,Fruits Flavour)I want these all Categories to Show delivery day

if( has_term( 'Cakes', 'product_cat' ) ) {
function BN_delievery_day() {

```
date_default_timezone_set("'Asia/Kolkata'");  
$thresshold = '1800';         
$time =date("Hi");

if ($time < $thresshold && $time > '0000') {
$delivery_day = 'today';
}
else {
$delivery_day = 'tomorrow';
}
  
   echo 'Delievery: '.$delivery_day;
```

}
}add_action ('woocommerce_share','BN_delievery_day');

Answer (score 0):

Use can use code like this:

```php
function bn_delievery_day() {
    global $product;

    // Check if the product has categories. Use the category slug instead of the category name.
    if ( ! has_term( array( 'cakes', 'chocos-flavour', 'fruits-flavour' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        // Skip if the product doesn't have a matching category.
        return;
    }

    // Write your php code here to display delivery texts.
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bn_delievery_day', 45 );
```